# Can't figure out this Statistics normal distribution problem

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

One 16-ounce bottle of an energy drink has an average of 400 mg of caffeine with a standard deviation of 20 mg. What is the probability that the average caffeine in a sample of 25 bottles is no more than 395 milligrams?

Comment: Hint: for two random variables $X$ and $Y$, $\mu(aX + bY) = a\mu(X) + b\mu(Y)$ and $\sigma^2(aX + bY) = a^2\sigma^2(X) + b^2 \sigma^2(Y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a statement in your book about the 'sampling distribution
of the sample mean' along with a statement of the Central Limit Theorem (CLT).
You should find that discussion and see how it matches my outline of the
solution below. Some of the notation may be slightly different.

If you have a random sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ from a population with
mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ (variance $\sigma^2),$ then
$E(\bar X) = \mu,$ $Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/n,$ and $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$
Also, according to the CLT, as $n$ increases the distribution of $\bar X$
tends to be normally distributed: $\bar X \stackrel{aprx}{\sim}
\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n}).$

Thus, assuming that $n = 25$ is large enough that $\bar X$ is nearly
normally distributed according to the CLT, you can use the relationship
$\bar X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 400, \sigma = 4).$ [Why $\sigma = 4?$]

Then you seek
$P(\bar X \le 395).$ 
You can approximate this by standardizing and using
printed tables of the standard normal distribution. Alternatively, you can
use software to get the result. Computation using standard normal tables
begins as follows:

$$P(\bar X \le 395) = P\left(\frac{\bar X -400}{4} \le \frac{395 -400}{4}\right) \approx  P(Z \le - 1.25) = ??$$

Using R statistical software the answer is obtained as follows:

```
pnorm(395, 400, 4)
## 0.1056498
```

In the plot below, you want the area to the left of the dotted red line.

[image]